# Flutter Listview with scrollbar

Tags: listview, flutter, scrollbar

Is there any way to put the scrollbar in a Listview?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView` inside `ScrollBar` widget

```
Scrollbar(
  child: ListView(),
)
```

More info: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html